Issue with MoveIt2 on ROS2 Foxy: "Robot model parameter not found" in hello_moveit executable
I am using MoveIt2 on the ROS2 Foxy distribution and have successfully set up MoveIt2. I can launch the Panda robot simulator in RViz by running the following command:
ros2 launch moveit2_tutorials demo.launch.py rviz_config:=panda_moveit_config_demo.rviz
RViz loads up fine, and I can interact with the Panda simulator as expected.
I followed the MoveIt2 tutorial (https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/your_first_project/your_first_project.html#further-reading) to create the hello_moveit executable. However, when I run the executable:
ros2 run hello_moveit hello_moveit
I encounter the following error:
[INFO] [1725799311.567308125] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Robot model parameter not found! Did you remap 'robot_description'?
[FATAL] [1725799311.567389458] [move_group_interface]: Unable to construct robot model. Please make sure all needed information is on the parameter server.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  Unable to construct robot model. Please make sure all needed information is on the parameter server.
What I've Tried:
I've verified that the Panda robot simulator works fine in RViz.
The error seems to suggest that the robot_description parameter is not being loaded into the node, but I'm not sure how to correctly pass it.
Question:
How can I properly load the robot_description parameter when running the hello_moveit executable to avoid this error? I want to move the panda arm. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
